# aumentar y disminuir t setinterval con localstorage

Tags: javascript, html

tengo unos botones que aumentan la velocidad de un barrido automático que tengo programado, cada botón aumenta un poco la velocidad, lo tengo así porque no me termina de salir un botón que aumente gradualmente la velocidad y otro que la reduzca...

Así lo tengo ahora mismo:

```
function aumentar() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    t = setInterval(clickbutton, 2000);
    localStorage.setItem('duracion', '2000')
}

function aumentar_mas() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    t = setInterval(clickbutton, 1000);
    localStorage.setItem('duracion', '1000')
}

function aumentar_mas_mas() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    t = setInterval(clickbutton, 500);
    localStorage.setItem('duracion', '500')
}
```

Me gustaría una función que aumentara la velocidad por ejemplo en 500 y otra que la redujera.

He intentado algo así pero no termina de funcionar:

```
n = 3000;
function mas() {
n = n - 500;
t = setInterval(clickbutton,n);
localStorage.setItem('duracion', 'n')
```

¿alguien sabría ayudarme?

Comment: para guardar el valor storage.setItem('duracion', n); para verlo localStorage.getItem('duracion'); no veo donde asignas n en tu codigo del localStorage

Answer (score 1):

En tu ejemplo solo tienes que cambiar la siguiente linea:

```
localStorage.setItem('duracion', n);
```

coloque ademas un ejemplo sencillo y practico sin usar localStorage

```js
var n = 3000;
function modificaTiempo(tiempo){
 n = n + parseInt(tiempo);
 alert(n);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="modificaTiempo(-50)">
Bajar Tiempo
</button>
<button onclick="modificaTiempo(50)">
Subir Tiempo
</button>
```

puedes guardar la variable en el localstorage o como quieras solo debes cambiar el

```
n = n + parseInt(tiempo);
```

por

```
localstorage.setItem('duracion' , parseInt(localstorage.getItem('duracion')) + parseInt(tiempo));
```

ejemplo practico de esto en https://jsfiddle.net/2enr8jgv/1/

Answer (score 0):

El siguiente código podrás usarlo para reemplazar las 3 rutinas que tienes para aumentar la velocidad.

Ejemplo:

```
var n = 3000, t = 0;
localStorage.setItem('duracion', 'n')

function mas() {
 clearTimeout(t);
 n = localStorage.getItem('duracion') - 500;
 t = setInterval(clickbutton,n);
 localStorage.setItem('duracion', 'n');
}
```

Con unos pequeños cambios puedes reutilizar la rutina tanto para aumentar como para disminuir la velocidad.

Ejemplo:

```
var n = 3000, incremento = 500, t = 0;
localStorage.setItem('duracion', 'n')

function velocidad(incremento) {
 clearTimeout(t);
 n = localStorage.getItem('duracion') + incremento;
 t = setInterval(clickbutton,n);
 localStorage.setItem('duracion', 'n');
}
velocidad(incremento); // para Aumentar la Velocidad
velocidad(-incremento); // para Disminuir la Velocidad
```

Comment: Hola! gracias por vuestras respuestas. Desgraciadamente no me termina de funcionar con vuestras sugerencias.